# How can I write a Google Chrome extension to enable/disable showing images?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just want to add a button that simply turn off or on showing images instead of going to the option - content setting.

I know how to make a hello world , what's the code to do the above?

Answer (score 4):

There is already an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/delbndpnablebhjofgcplkkiadolmbdi) that does that. After a quick glance at the code it looks like it is a simple css injection that sets visibility to hidden for all `img` tags and removes background images from all tags.

**Update**.
Also there is an `beforeload` event in Safari/Chrome that is supposed to fire before an external resource (image) is loaded, so you can probably make more efficient image blocker. I haven't tried it myself but you can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW9).

Comment: That still doesn't remove the images, they are still loaded (bandwidth used). When the HTTP request blocking lands, this could be done more efficiently, block those resources from every loading.

Answer (score -2):

You could go to content settings and then find there images settings. Setting **Do not show any images** will block all images, but in location bar you can easily manage exceptions.

I Hope that helps.

Comment: 1. "instead of going to the option - content setting" - stated in the question. 2. Suppose I want to see images on the site once and don't want to turn them on for this site forever. The current way is to enable it forever, look at them, then go to content settings, find the site in list (that may be quite long) and remove it from the list. Not quite convenient, isn't it?